# Sum of random variables and boundedness

Tags: probability, measure-theory, inequality

I have some sequence of random variables $(\xi^1, \cdots , \xi^N)$ which are not necessarily iid . I'm trying to show that the following expectation is uniformly bounded for all $N$
$$ \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \sum_{i = 1}^N W^N _i(\xi^1, ..., \xi^N)A^N _i(\xi^1, ..., \xi^N) / B^N _i(\xi^1,...,\xi^N) \bigg]$$
and have the following informations:

- $ \sup_N \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \sum_{i = 1}^N W^N(\xi^1, ..., \xi^N) \bigg]$ is finite and $A^N _i(\xi^1, ..., \xi^N)$ are bounded almost surely for all $N$.
- $B^N _i(\xi^1,...,\xi^N)$ converges to some function $B_i < \infty$ almost surely. We also have a Hoeffding inequality for the difference $\big| B^N _i(\xi^1,...,\xi^N) - B_i \big|$ (from which we can deduce $L_q$ error etc...).

I've tried all sorts of classic techniques but i've been unsuccessful so far.

Thank you in advance